# Javascript RegExp find with condition but without showing them

Tags: regex, grouping, conditional-statements

I'm trying to find the words between the brackets.

```
var str = "asdfasdfkjh {{word1}} asdf fff fffff {{word2}} asdfasdf";
var pattern = /{{\w*}}/g;
var str.match(pattern);  // ["{{word1}}","{{word2}}"]
```

This closes the deal, but gives it with the brackets, and i don't want them.
Sure, if I used the native replace on the results i could remove them. But i want the regexp to do the same.

I've also tried:
    var pattern = /(?:{{)(\w*)(?:}})/g

but i can't find the real deal. Could you help me?

Edit: i might need to add a note that the words are dynamic

solution:

Bases on Tim Piezcker awnser i came with this solution:

```
var arr = [],      
re = /{{(\w?)}}/g,item;

while (item = re.exec(s))
arr.push(item[1]);
```

Comment: Bases on Tim Piezcker awnser i came with this solution:

var arr = [],      
     re = /{{(\w?)}}/g,item;
            
    while (item = re.exec(s))
    arr.push(item[1]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most regex flavors, you could use lookaround assertions:

```
(?<={{)\w*(?=}})
```

Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind assertions, so you can't use them.

But the regex you proposed can be used by accessing the first capturing group:

```
var pattern = /{{(\w*)}}/g;
var match = pattern.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution would be `/[^{]+(?=\}\})/`, but it will cause a bit of a mess if the leading braces are omitted, and will also match `{word1}}`. If I remember correctly, JavaScript does not support look-behind, which is a bit of a shame in this case.

Comment: Good idea. I like this. I guess the corner case `{word1}}` wouldn't be problematic, but only @user1671224 would be able to judge that.

Comment: Agreed, it ain't problemetic but it could result in some unexpected difficulties.

Comment: Fair enough. I would probably have gone with capturing groups, too.